# John Resig's online JS tutorial #13 & #14

Tags: javascript

http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#13
http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#14

On #13, with my Java background, I don't really understand what is happening, and why #14 is a solution that fixes the problem.

```
var ninja = { 
  yell: function(n){ 
    return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
  } 
}; 
assert( ninja.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "A single object isn't too bad, either." ); 

var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell }; 
var ninja = null; 

try { 
  samurai.yell(4); 
} catch(e){ 
  assert( false, "Uh, this isn't good! Where'd ninja.yell go?" ); 
}
```

VS

```
var ninja = { 
  yell: function yell(n){ 
    return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
  } 
}; 
assert( ninja.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "Works as we would expect it to!" ); 

var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell }; 
var ninja = {}; 
assert( samurai.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "The method correctly calls itself." );
```

Can someone explain better this code?
I have a Java/Scala background and this seems really strange to me. I guess I don't yet understand how variables and objects are stored in JS.

I don't understand why on the first we can't call `samurai.yell(4);`

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it a bit more specific? "can someone explain this code" is very vague and it would be better if the question were self contained without needing to read the external links.

Comment: I've edited to make it more clear but it seems obvious that the parts I don't understand are the last asserted lines :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code you posted is that the "yell" function requires that the outer-scope variable "ninja" retains a reference to the object. If it's changed (as it is in your example; it's set to `null`), then the function doesn't work.

In the example you didn't post, it's fixed:

```
var ninja = { 
  yell: function yell(n){ 
    return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
  } 
};
```

The function is instantiated with a name ("yell") after the `function` keyword. That name will be available inside the function as a reference to itself, so there's no more dependency on the variable "ninja".

Comment: ooooh ok I didn't see it was called recursively using `ninja.yell(n-1)`. So the first call can find the yell method but once in the method it can't find the yell method anymore right? I thought the exception was raised because of the very first call of yell which would have been strange

Comment: Right, it's that embedded reference to "ninja" in the first one that's the problem. It leaves the code in a fragile state. In the second (#14) version, that symbol "yell" inside the function will *always* refer to the function.